# Is Raspberry Pi 4 fast enough to watch online videos with 1080p?

Tags: streaming-video, web-browsers, youtube, pi-4

The Pi 4 has a faster processor (1.5 GHz Quad-Core ARM-Cortex A72). I am wondering if it is now possible to watch HTML5 videos on a browser (for example YouTube) and with 1080p quality without lagging and sticking?

Comment: The GPU on the Pi is plenty fast to _show_ 1080p full screen video fluently even on the first Raspberry.  So this is a software problem, not a hardware problem.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not all 1080p videos are the same. Check out HEVC for instance.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No problem then.  Then let's put it like that even the first Raspberry Pi (which predates HECV) can show full HD MPEG-4 h.264 videos because the GPU has hardware decoding.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure, but HTML5 videos are not limited to h.264.

Answer (score 4):

In [this review](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/raspberry-pi-4-model-b-review-this-board-really-can-replace-your-pc/), RPi 4 was able to play a 1080p30 Youtube video smoothly, but not 1080p60. There was observable screen tearing, but I'd expect the situation to improve in this regard as Raspbian is polished for RPi 4 support.

Note that there's also a [method](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=193811) to offload the video playback from the browser to an external video player, which sometimes was the only option for smooth online playback on older RPi with their limited memory and slower CPUs. It will probably improve the playback on RPi 4 as well, but it may well be no longer necessary if Raspbian gets enough polishing to support a flawless in-browser playback.